# How to repeat a command if an error arise in R?

Tags: r, error-handling

I was wondering how to tell the script to redo a command if an error arises.
The Biomod2 package is giving me a random error, and I wish to give a command to tell the script to redo the model until the model is complete well.

What I mean is something similar to the python command "try/except"

Comment: See if this would help you at all https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193779/how-to-use-the-trycatch-function

Comment: Thank you stefan_aus_hannover, however, if the error rises, tryCatch does not restart the loop until the error appears.